# How to link a customer's addresses to a specific address

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-address, address

How to point all customer's addresses to one specific address? When a new customer is created, the address ID is assigned to the customer's shipping and billing, but it seems that the address' `parent_id` is set to the latest created customer. In other words I want to change the 1-to-1 --> 1-to-many in address-customer relationship with minimum impact on everything else.

I've done a trace in `\Magento\Customer\Model\Address::setCustomerId($id)` by

```
$e = new \Exception();
var_dump(explode("\n", $e->getTraceAsString()));die;
```

and got (first lines)

```
array(57) {
  [0]=>
  string(131) "#0 /var/www/magento/magento2/sandbox/vendor/magento/framework/DataObject.php(207): Magento\Customer\Model\Address->setCustomerId(5)"
  [1]=>
  string(158) "#1 /var/www/magento/magento2/sandbox/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Address.php(150): Magento\Framework\DataObject->setDataUsingMethod('customer_id', 5)"
  [2]=>
  string(203) "#2 /var/www/magento/magento2/sandbox/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/AddressRepository.php(115): Magento\Customer\Model\Address->updateData(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Address))"
  [3]=>
  string(222) "#3 /var/www/magento/magento2/sandbox/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerRepository.php(212): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\AddressRepository->save(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Address))"
  [4]=>
  string(202) "#4 /var/www/magento/magento2/sandbox/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository->save(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), NULL)"
```

where would be the appropriate place, should I skip the `setCustomer()` or will it affect the address integrity?

*Note:*
I've also had to override `\Sqli\User\Model\Quote\QuoteAddressValidator::validate($addressData)` to skip the verification of if a cusomter's addressId references an address that have that customer in it's `parent_id`.

Comment: I tried to change some things, please need advice in the way of posting questions

Comment: I had to override `setCustomer()` in `\Magento\Customer\Model\Address`, and `getAddressesCollection()` in `\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer` in order to get that specific address instead of the customer's own.

Answer (score 0):

in customer Model, I had to override here, from the source of the problem:

```
public function getAddressesCollection()
{
    if ($this->_addressesCollection === null) {
        $this->_addressesCollection = $this->getAddressCollection()->setCustomerFilter(
            $this->getParentCustomer()
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            '*'
        );
    }
    return $this->_addressesCollection;
}
```

then I had to override address Model's `setCustomer` with something like

```
public function setCustomer(Customer $customer)
{
    if($customer->getParentCustomer() !== null){
        $this->_customer = $customer->getParentCustomer();
        $this->setCustomerId($this->_customer->getId());
        return $this;
    }
    return parent::setCustomer($customer);
}
```